# Toggle button not working in bootstrap 4 and angular 7 app for navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am working with Angular7 and Botstrap4.
trying to add navbar in my app, when navbar is collapsed, toggle button not working.

I don't want to add ng-bootstrap, only bootstrap4.

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{title}}</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contact">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you imported BootstrapJS files.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution to this problem is to import the scripts for jquery, popper and bootstrap intot the index.html file of your application. Doing this will allow your navbar dropdown collapsed nav-links.

i did this and it works very well for me.
See sample below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you forgot to include the `bootstrap.min.js`, `jquery.min.js`, and `popper.min.js` file links in `angular.json` where you already put the `bootstrap.min.css`.

```
"styles": [
 "src/styles.css",
 "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./node_modules/popperjs/dist/popper.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case in an angular 13 application I had to change `data-bs-toggle` to `data-toggle` and `data-bs-dismiss` to `data-dismiss` for close button and it is working well.